# What do you call a gas / petrol station for planes?

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't believe Gas Station or Petrol Station fit as they are normally used for cars.

Is there an official term for a fuel station specific to planes?

Comment: Perhaps [Aircraft Fuel Servicing Location](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/32668)?

Comment: @jxh Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: @MetaEd I understand the request, but I don't know if it's an answer, which is why I made a comment.

Comment: @jxh better to make it an answer anyway. If you want others to expand on it: make it a community answer. If others think it's bad (i.e. you get more down than up votes) you can always delete it and you won't lose rep. You won't lose rep for community answers anyway. ;) Edit: seems like a good answer with source, so would be an up vote from me ^^.

Comment: @JJJ Probably a meta discussion, but in lieu of research from the OP, the asker can use comments as a basis for improving their question.

Comment: This is taken from my experience working for a company located at an airport: Most people would have the "fuel truck" come by and fill their tanks, but occasionally people would take their plane over to the "pump", or to the "fuel pump". I would add this as an answer, but the question's [on hold], so I can't.

Comment: Doesn't this entirely depend on the airport and the fuelling system in place. In some places, e.g.smaller airports, aircraft will be fuelled from tankers. However at London Heathrow, I happen to know that aviation fuel arrives on site pumped underground from port terminals/refineries. My guess is that each departure gate has a pumping point. Surely no one wants large aircraft meandering around to fill up.

Comment: @WS2 a perfectly valid point, I should have clarified that in my scenario was in the instance that if the plane and to go to a specific place to refuel, what would that place be.

Comment: This Question would be better suited to Aviation.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a specific word for it, any more than there is a specific word for the car variety. (Even though **gas station** seems the most common.)

In general, for cars or airplanes, I've seen *gas station*, *filling station*, *fuel station*, and *petrol station*.

In the following specific references to airplanes, the emphasized text is mine.

From the Gizmodo article ["The Military's New Flying Gas Station Will Be Open 24/7 Worldwide"](https://gizmodo.com/the-militarys-new-flying-gas-station-will-be-open-24-7-484398864):

> KC-135 Stratotanker planes have been refueling fighter craft in-flight for more than 60 years. While such longevity is commendable, the US military’s fleet of mid-air refuellers is in desperate need of an update. And that’s where this new flying **gas station** comes in.

From the Edenvale Aerodrome [website](http://www.edenflight.com/fuel-station.html):

> Edenvale Aerodrome has a state-of-the-art **Fuel Station** which offers JET A1A fuel, Avgas 100LL and Mogas 91 Octane.

From ["How to Use the Fuel Station in FSX"](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-use-the-fuel-station-in-fsx) on Techwalla:

> Park your airplane in a **fuel station** which is located next to clearly marked fuel trucks. Check to make sure you that you're parking in a spot that's appropriate for your aircraft's size.

I'm sure there are other references I could hunt down. But based only on these, and if you find too much of an association between **gas station** and cars, **fuel station** seems like a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-base_operator)

A **fixed-base operator** (FBO) is an organization granted the right by an airport to operate at the airport and provide aeronautical services such as **fueling**, hangaring, tie-down and parking, aircraft rental, aircraft maintenance, flight instruction, and similar services.

Some call fueling stations at airports **fuel farms**.